# Regular Expression to handle multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with a javascript regular expression that satisfies the following conditions (it is to validate input in textarea):

1. there should be minimum 3 characters
2. the first character is always /
3. the entire input string shouldnot match the exact string '/abc' and '/xyz' but it can be anyother like /abce or /abct etc...

Ex: the input such as /xyzw, /ab, /abcd, /asdad are accepted and such as /a, /abc etc. are not accepted

Comment: `/^\/(?!abc$|xyz$)[\S\s]{2,}/`

Comment: Your condition 3 needs clarification. It can't match `/xyz` but then later that *is* ok?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/^\/(?!abc$|xyz$)[\S\s]{2,}/
```

Meaning:

```
/             
^             Start of string
\/            "/"
(?!abc$|xyz$) Not followed by only abc or xyz ($ = end of string)
[\S\s]{2,}    At least two characters.
/
```

Comment: Sorry... my bad.. it was a typo.. changed it now!!

Comment: Hi Rob, 
I have tried the solution given by you as follows:

var existing = "";
if(disk.isLinux)
return "^/" + existing + "[^/](?!abc$|xyz$)[a-zA-Z]{0,}[^/]$";

But this didnt work for me...

Comment: It can accept inputs /ab, /xy, /abcd, /xyzw but not the inputs /xyz, /abc

Comment: What are you trying to implement? Your previous comment is a plain string, not a RegEx. If you want to match `/` or `/ab`, but not `/abc` or `/boot/` or `/usr/bin`, use `return "^/" + existing + "(?!abc$|xyz$)[a-zA-Z]{0,}$";`.

Comment: thanks Rob.. thanks a lot for your patience and explanation. It worked!!